# Open WordPress post in a popup on the same page, with working href location with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, post, popup, location

I want to open WordPress posts in a popup on the same page without reloading the window. When a post opens in the popup, the location url needs to be the permalink of the post. In this case people can copy the link and it will open the single post page. Another important requirement is while clicking the back button in the browser, you will go through posts you have visited.

**Example website with the same function:**

- https://www.behance.net/

If you click on a post on the example website, the post will open in a popup. The location href is changing to the post url. And posts you have visited will open in the popup if you click on the back button in the browser.

**Open posts in popup**

To open posts in popups i'm using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/). This the code:

*HTML:*

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="openInPopup">
</a>
```

*jQuery*:

```
$("a.openInPopup").colorbox();
```

**Location href**

For the href location I've tried multiple things. If I use `window.location = url` it will reload the page so that isn't an option.

I found out about the [HTML 5 History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). I have implement this API with the Colorbox code like this:

```
$("a.openInPopup").colorbox({
      onComplete:function(){
          var url = $(this).attr('href');
          history.pushState({}, '', url); //Add url to the href location when Colorbox is finished
      },
      onCleanup: function(){
          history.back(); //Remove url from href location when Colorbox is closed
      }
});
```

This add the permalink structure of the post to the href location when the post opens in the popup, and it removes it when the popup is closed.

There is only one big issue: the back button in the browser doesn't work. As you can see in the example website, you can click trough the history when clicking on the back button in the browser. Posts you have visited will open in the popup if you go back.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must use popstate event handler.

For example

```html
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        if (event.state != null){
            document.location.href = documen.location;
        }
    });
```